# c++ оператор "this" можно использовать только внутри нестатической функции-члена

Tags: c++, opengl

Я пишу код opengl и в классе мне нужно передать приватную переменную vbo с помощью this в функцию, которая как я полагаю является статической.

Ошибка на 28 строке glBindBuffer(type, this->VBO[index]);

Вот код:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <string>

class Object
{
public:
    Object(GLuint VAO, GLuint VBO[]);
    ~Object();

    void SetBufferData(int index, GLenum type, float numbers[], int size, GLenum normalize);

private:
    GLuint VBO[];
};

Object::Object(GLuint VAO, GLuint VBO[])
{
    std::copy(VBO, VBO + sizeof(VBO), this->VBO);
}

Object::~Object()
{
}

void SetBufferData(int index, GLenum type, float numbers[], int size, GLenum normalize)
{
    glBindBuffer(type, this->VBO[index]);
}
```

Comment: Функция `SetBufferData` не является реализацией функции этого класса. Забыли написать `Object::`

Comment: Понял. Огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Не относится к проблеме напрямую, однако объявление  `GLuint VBO[];` и все связанные действия с ним являются невалидными. Используйте `::std::vector`. Аргументы функций навроде `GLuint VBO[]` - хотя и являются валидными, но делают в итоге совсем не то, что вы думаете.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй добавить в класс friend void SetBufferData(int index, GLenum type, float numbers[], int size, GLenum normalize);

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Духсообщества, всё в ответе понятно, просто он неправильный.